# What does the ending of MOSFET name mean?

Tags: mosfet

I’m trying to find alternative for TSM2301A MOSFET, but I only found `SI2301CDS-T1-GE3`. From what I understand the `2301A` is general “name” of the MOSFET, but:

What does the “A” mean?

Or what doesn't the CDS mean?

What it changes?

Can I use [this mosfet](https://www.conrad.cz/p/vishay-si2301cds-t1-ge3-tranzistor-mosfet-1-p-kanal-16-w-sot-23-3-597293) instead of TSM2301A?

I’m completely new to MOSFETs, so please excuse me if I ask stupid questions.

Comment: Did you find and compare both the datasheets for the original FET, and your proposed replacement?

Comment: It's pretty much up to each manufacturer to establish their own nomenclature, but there are also many common denominators between different manufacturers nomenclatures. Vishay is normally good a explaining it in their datasheets, but this one had little information " Si2301CDS-T1-E3 (Lead (Pb)-free)
 Si2301CDS-T1-GE3 (Lead (Pb)-free and Halogen-free)".

Comment: I did, but I don’t understand them at all, so I don’t know if they can be used for the same thing.